# Что-то не так с кодом

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:length(h)
    out=MyInteg(y,a,b,h(i));
    o=tub(a;b;h(i));
    MaxEr1(i)=max(abs(o(:,1)-out(:,1)));
    MaxEr2(i)=max(abs(o(:,2)-out(:,2)));
    out=[];
    o=[];
end
```

Прошу вас помочь. Скинули код, но я никак не пойму, что за функция tub, она и не работает, но, по-видимому, она должна делать матрицу 1х3, чтобы можно было делать дальнейшие действия.
Её или недописали, когда код копировали, или что, но суть в том, что я так и не нашел её.

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @wiillko93, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Что означает "функция tub, она и не работает"? как это выражается? Матлаб ее найти не может или она выдает не те результаты что должна? В первом случае именно что не скопировали ее (она вполне могла валяться в какой-то из видимых матлабу директорий и тот кто копировал даже не знал что она там есть). 
Ну а во втором никто вам не сможет определить что именно не так в функции которой нет (а я такой в матлабе не помню, хотя и не претентдую на точную память всего что). Могу только подсказать в пару приколов при переносе с машины на машину (вообще, у меня было подозрение что это отличие 6.5 и 7.0, но не проверял):

1. другой порядок просмотра папок (на одном компе сначала просматривалась рабочая дирректория и подцеплялась функция inf, на другой сначала просматривались системные и цеплялась бесконечность)
2. на одном компе 1:10 давал строку, а на втором столбец